# Выборка содержимого тэга с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: html, c++, регулярные-выражения, парсер

К примеру, у нас есть следующий html-код:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <caption>Hello!</caption>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nameCl">
            Block Content
        </div>
        <p>Text</p>
        <i name="nameI" size = "2" with=6>Content</i>
    </body>
</html>
```

Как можно с помощью регулярных выражений получить содержание оперделенного тэга, указав его имя в этом выражении. Имена тэгов в файле зарание известны и могут передваться в качестве строки или параметра функции, которая и будет осуществлять выборку. 
К примеру, если я хочу получить содержимое тэга **html**, то результат выполнения регулярки должен быть следующим:

```
<head>
   <caption>Hello!</caption>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="nameCl">
        Block Content
   </div>
   <p>Text</p>
        <i name="nameI" size = "2" with=6>Content</i>
</body>
```

Для тэга **body** результат должен быть таким:

```
<div class="nameCl">
    Block Content
</div>
<p>Text</p>
<i name="nameI" size = "2" with=6>Content</i>
```

и тд.
Я попробовал решить эту задачу, написав следующее регулярное выражение:

```
<html>([\w\s]*)<\/html>
```

Однако, я не получил  необходимый результат. 
Далее, попробовал еще один способ:

```
<.+>\s*(.+)\s*<\/.+>
```

В целом, результат получился почти необходимым, однако, если делать выборку содержимого тэга **html**, то результат будет таким:

```
<head>
        <caption>Hello!</caption>
    </head>
        <div class="nameCl">
            Block Content
        </div>
        <p>Text</p>
        <i name="nameI" size = "2" with=6>Content</i>
    </body>
```

т.е. нет начального тэга .

**EDIT**

Реализация второго способа выглядит вот так:

```
std::regex m_RegexValue("<.+>\\s*(.+)\\s*<\\/.+>")
std::vector<std::string> result {};

    try
    {
        std::sregex_iterator next(userData.begin(), userData.end(), m_RegexValue);
        std::sregex_iterator end;

        while (next != end)
        {
            result.push_back(std::smatch(*next).str());
            ++next;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::regex_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

Как можно это исправить и получить желаемый результат, т.е. чтобы по имени тэга получить все его содержимое?

**UPDATE**

После того, как принял советы, которые мне здесь подсказали, возникла потребность выбрать не всё содержимое родительского тега, а лишь чистый текст/контент, без остальных дочерних тегов.
Т.е. к примеру, есть следующее содержимое html-страницы:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <caption>Hello!</caption>
        </head>
        Some content/data/text
        <body>
            <div class="nameCl">
                Block Content
            </div>
            <p>Text</p>
            <i name="nameI" size = "2" with=6>Content</i>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Как можно выбрать только *Some content/data/text*?
Данная проблема возникла потому, что в некоторых случаях нужно выбирать абсолютно все содержимое родительского тега, а в других - только чистый текст/контент родительского тега.

Comment: В C++ помощью `std::regex` никак - нет поддержки рекурсии. `R"(<(html)>([\w\W]*?)</\1>)"` не сработает для вложенных тегов.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , я обновил свое описание и добавил свой пример реализации для второго случая. Такая реализация мне почти подходит за исключением того, что она не захватывает начальны тег <body>. Может, можно как-то подправить мою текущую регулярку для того, чтобы она захватывала все?

Comment: `m_RegexValue("<([a-zA-Z_][\\w.-]*)[^>]*>\\s*([\\w\\W]*?)\\s*</\\1>")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно в таких случаях использовать специальные парсеры DOM.

Я приведу пример регулярного выражения, который может не всегда сработать, например:

- если в атрибутах есть `<` или `>`
- если требуется найти соответсвтующий закрывающий тег для открывающего (т.е. без поддержки вложенных тегов.

Держа вышесказанное в уме, посмотрите на

```
m_RegexValue("<([a-zA-Z_][\\w.-]*)[^>]*>\\s*([\\w\\W]*?)\\s*</\\1>")
```

Шаблон `([a-zA-Z_][\w.-]*)[^>]*>\s*([\w\W]*?)\s*</\1>` находит:

- `([a-zA-Z_][\w.-]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1 (техническая, нужна для того, чтобы потом использовать обратную ссылку на значение, захваченное этой группой): ASCII-буква или `_`, за которой может следовать 0 и более букв, цифр, `_`, `.` и `-`
- `[^>]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `>`
- `>\s*` - `>` и 0 и более пробельных символов
- `([\w\W]*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `\s*</\1>` -  0 и более пробельных символов, а затем `</`, обратная ссылка на значение первой захватывающей группы и `>`.

Для нахожения определённых тегов, можно указывать их внутри первых скобок, а после добавлять границу слова. Пример для `body`:

```
<(body)\b[^>]*>\s*([\w\W]*?)\s*</\1>
  ^^^^ ^^
```

[См. онлайн-демо этого выражения](https://regex101.com/r/uFTb8j/1).

**Однако** использовать эту регулярку не рекомендуется, используйте соответствующий парсер. Сссылки на разные HTML-парсеры для С++ можно найти [в этом ответе на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18105023/3832970).

Comment: Можно данное решение адаптировать и под случай, который я описал в топике в пункте "UPDATE"? У меня, к сожалению, не получилось, используя Ваш пример, достичь желаемого результата, чтобы выбрать только текст.

Comment: @igdev Регулярки и HTML не дружат, это "костыль", так как в каждом конкретном случае придётся поправлять регулярку (и что не всегда будет возможно). Вам на самом деле стоит обратить внимание на парсеры HTML. А реугелярка в данном случае может выглядеть так - [`</head>\s*([^<>]*?)\s*<body>`](https://regex101.com/r/uFTb8j/3). Однако никакой гарантии.

Answer (score 2):

Решение задачи можно получить проще если использовать SAX/DOM XML-парсеры. Например, в Qt есть замечательный метод [QDomElement::elementsByTagName(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomelement.html#elementsByTagName), который возвращает список всех дочерних элементов с указанным именем, а [QDomElement::toString()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#toString) возвращает содержимое элемента в качестве строки. Это все что нужно для того, что бы решить Вашу задачу.

Конечно, никто не заставляет использовать Qt, и Вы можете применить здесь любой другой XML-парсер.

Answer (score 1):

Для подобного разложения используются лексеры и парсеры. Пример сочетания - `flex+bison`. [Хорошая статья](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html) , описывающая работу лексера и парсера вместе.

P. S. В лексере, для улавливания морфем используются регулярные выражения.